# creating turnjs instance before add any pages

Tags: pdf.js, turnjs, turn.js

I want to add dynamic pages from pdf from page one without cover page. But, I could not create turnjs instance without page inside(cover page that has been hardcoded in html). It output error:

> Uncaught (in promise) b {name: "TurnJsError", message: "The page 1 does not exist"}

But, we could not use addpages method of turnjs without declare turnjs instance. How to achieve this?

Currently, I hardcoded cover page in html $('#book').

```
<div id="book">
    <div class="cover">
        <h1>Cover</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, I create turnjs instance as follow:

```
$('#book').turn({
                   page: 1,
                   autoCenter: true,                                            
                });
```

Then, I remove cover page by:

```
$("#book").turn("removePage", 1);
```

After that, I start adding pages from pdf. So, it meets my requirement.

Complete code

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('plugin/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html_p1 = 'Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages, typically consisting of alphabetic and numeric characters, between two or more users of mobile devices, desktops/laptops, or other type of compatible computer. Text messages may be sent over a cellular network, or may also be sent via an Internet connection';
//echo $html;
$pdf->writeHTML($html_p1, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html_p2 = 'A telephone call is a connection over a telephone network between the called party and the calling party.';
$pdf->writeHTML($html_p2, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html_p3 = 'On the Internet, @ (pronounced "at" or "at sign" or "address sign") is the symbol in an e-mail address that separates the name of the user from the users Internet address, as in this hypothetical e-mail address example: msmuffet@tuffet.org. In business, @ is a symbol meaning "at" or "each."';
$pdf->writeHTML($html_p3, true, 0, true, 0);
$base64PdfString = $pdf->Output('', 'E');
$base64PdfArray  = explode("\r\n", $base64PdfString);
$base64          = '';
for($i = 5; $i < count($base64PdfArray); $i++){
    $base64 .= $base64PdfArray[$i];
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                background: #ccc;
            }
            #book
            {
                width: 800px;
                height: 500px;
            }

            #book .turn-page
            {
                background-color: white;
            }

            #book .cover
            {
                background: #333;
            }

            #book .cover h1
            {
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 50px;
                line-height: 500px;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            #book .loader
            {
                background-image: url(loader.gif);
                width: 24px;
                height: 24px;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 238px;
                left: 188px;
            }

            #book .data
            {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 40px;
                color: #999;
                line-height: 500px;
            }

            #controls
            {
                width: 800px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 20px 0px;
                font: 30px arial;
            }

            #controls input, #controls label
            {
                font: 30px arial;
            }

            #book .odd
            {
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
            }

            #book .even
            {
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/turnjs4/lib/turn.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/pdfjs_ex/pdf.js"></script>
        <script>
            const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) =>
            {
                const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
                const byteArrays = [];

                for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize)
                {
                    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
                    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
                    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++)
                    {
                        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
                }

                const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
                return blob;
            }
            function addPage(page, book, pdf_doc)
            {
                if (!book.turn('hasPage', page))
                {
                    var element = $('<div />', {'class': 'page '+((page%2==0) ? 'odd' : 'even'), 'id': 'page-'+page}).html('<i class="loader"></i>');
                    book.turn('addPage', element, page);                                        
                    pdf_doc.getPage((page)).then(function(p)
                                    {
                                        var scale = 1;
                                        var viewport = p.getViewport(scale);

                                        var pag1        =document.createElement('canvas');
                                        pag1.id         ='Pg_1';
                                        var context1    =pag1.getContext('2d');
                                        pag1.height     =viewport.height;
                                        pag1.width      =viewport.width;

                                        var renderContext =
                                        {
                                            canvasContext: context1,
                                            viewport: viewport
                                        };

                                        p.render(renderContext).then(function()
                                            {
                                                pag1.toBlob(function(blob)
                                                {
                                                    var burl                        =URL.createObjectURL(blob); 

                                                setTimeout(function()
                                                    {
                                                        element.html('<div style="background-image:url('+burl+'); width: 400px; height: 500px; background-size: cover;"></div><div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1; width: 461px; height: 600px;"></div>');

                                                    }, 1000);
                                                })
                                            })
                                    })
                }
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="book">
            <div class="cover">
                <h1>
                    Cover
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).ready(function()
                {

                    const contentType   ='application/pdf';
                    const b64Data       ='<?php echo $base64;?>';
                    const blob          =b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);

                    const blobUrl       =URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                    PDFJS.getDocument({ url: blobUrl }).then(function(pdf_doc)
                    {
                        __PDF_DOC       = pdf_doc;
                        __TOTAL_PAGES   = __PDF_DOC.numPages;

                        $('#book').turn({
                                        page: 1,
                                        autoCenter: true,                                           
                                        });

                        var list = [];
                        for (var i = 1; i <= __TOTAL_PAGES; i++) 
                        {
                            list.push(i);
                        }
                        $("#book").turn("removePage", 1);
                        for (page = 0; page<list.length; page++)                        
                        addPage(list[page], $("#book"),pdf_doc);
                    })  
                });

            $(window).bind('keydown', function(e)
                {
                    if (e.target && e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()!='input')
                    if (e.keyCode==37)
                    $('#book').turn('previous');
                    else if (e.keyCode==39)
                    $('#book').turn('next');

                });

        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

But, I still want to know how to create turnjs instance with no pages and display as flipbook after adding all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are missing 1 line, which is to append the element you created inside addpage() funciton,
you should use

```
book.append(customDiv);
//OR you can write same thing as:
$('#book').append(element);
// So your Code mus be:
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('plugin/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html_p1 = 'Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages, typically consisting of alphabetic and numeric characters, between two or more users of mobile devices, desktops/laptops, or other type of compatible computer. Text messages may be sent over a cellular network, or may also be sent via an Internet connection';
//echo $html;
$pdf->writeHTML($html_p1, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html_p2 = 'A telephone call is a connection over a telephone network between the called party and the calling party.';
$pdf->writeHTML($html_p2, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html_p3 = 'On the Internet, @ (pronounced "at" or "at sign" or "address sign") is the symbol in an e-mail address that separates the name of the user from the users Internet address, as in this hypothetical e-mail address example: msmuffet@tuffet.org. In business, @ is a symbol meaning "at" or "each."';
$pdf->writeHTML($html_p3, true, 0, true, 0);
$base64PdfString = $pdf->Output('', 'E');
$base64PdfArray  = explode("\r\n", $base64PdfString);
$base64          = '';
for($i = 5; $i < count($base64PdfArray); $i++){
    $base64 .= $base64PdfArray[$i];
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                background: #ccc;
            }
            #book
            {
                width: 800px;
                height: 500px;
            }

            #book .turn-page
            {
                background-color: white;
            }

            #book .cover
            {
                background: #333;
            }

            #book .cover h1
            {
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 50px;
                line-height: 500px;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            #book .loader
            {
                background-image: url(loader.gif);
                width: 24px;
                height: 24px;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 238px;
                left: 188px;
            }

            #book .data
            {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 40px;
                color: #999;
                line-height: 500px;
            }

            #controls
            {
                width: 800px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 20px 0px;
                font: 30px arial;
            }

            #controls input, #controls label
            {
                font: 30px arial;
            }

            #book .odd
            {
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
            }

            #book .even
            {
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
                background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #ddd 100%);
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/turnjs4/lib/turn.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/pdfjs_ex/pdf.js"></script>
        <script>
            const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) =>
            {
                const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
                const byteArrays = [];

                for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize)
                {
                    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
                    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
                    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++)
                    {
                        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
                }

                const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
                return blob;
            }
            function addPage(page, book, pdf_doc)
            {
                if (!book.turn('hasPage', page))
                {
                    var element = $('<div />', {'class': 'page '+((page%2==0) ? 'odd' : 'even'), 'id': 'page-'+page}).html('<i class="loader"></i>');
                    book.turn('addPage', element, page);                                        
                    pdf_doc.getPage((page)).then(function(p)
                                    {
                                        var scale = 1;
                                        var viewport = p.getViewport(scale);

                                        var pag1        =document.createElement('canvas');
                                        pag1.id         ='Pg_1';
                                        var context1    =pag1.getContext('2d');
                                        pag1.height     =viewport.height;
                                        pag1.width      =viewport.width;

                                        var renderContext =
                                        {
                                            canvasContext: context1,
                                            viewport: viewport
                                        };

                                        p.render(renderContext).then(function()
                                            {
                                                pag1.toBlob(function(blob)
                                                {
                                                    var burl                        =URL.createObjectURL(blob); 

                                                setTimeout(function()
                                                    {
                                                        element.html('<div style="background-image:url('+burl+'); width: 400px; height: 500px; background-size: cover;"></div><div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1; width: 461px; height: 600px;"></div>');
book.append(element);

                                                    }, 1000);
                                                })
                                            })
                                    })
                }
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="book">
            <div class="cover">
                <h1>
                    Cover
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).ready(function()
                {

                    const contentType   ='application/pdf';
                    const b64Data       ='<?php echo $base64;?>';
                    const blob          =b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);

                    const blobUrl       =URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                    PDFJS.getDocument({ url: blobUrl }).then(function(pdf_doc)
                    {
                        __PDF_DOC       = pdf_doc;
                        __TOTAL_PAGES   = __PDF_DOC.numPages;

                        $('#book').turn({
                                        page: 1,
                                        autoCenter: true,                                           
                                        });

                        var list = [];
                        for (var i = 1; i <= __TOTAL_PAGES; i++) 
                        {
                            list.push(i);
                        }
                        $("#book").turn("removePage", 1);
                        for (page = 0; page<list.length; page++)                        
                        addPage(list[page], $("#book"),pdf_doc);
                    })  
                });

            $(window).bind('keydown', function(e)
                {
                    if (e.target && e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()!='input')
                    if (e.keyCode==37)
                    $('#book').turn('previous');
                    else if (e.keyCode==39)
                    $('#book').turn('next');

                });

        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```